# MySQL very slow query on mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Below is a query on a new server that I'm moving a site to. The existing query below is very fast on the original server running InnoDB. The new server that is MariaDB 5.6 this is exceptionally slow.

The only line that needs to be removed on the new server is "AND np.user_id!=su.id" and it becomes fast again.

The subquery has no effect on speed in any great way.

I don't know enough about different DB versions to have any idea of why this would be the case.

Can any one shed any light on the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
    np.id, np.user_id, np.post_id, np.response_id, np.viewed, np.clicked, np.emailed, np.timestamp,
    su.id AS suUserId, 
    su.fullname AS suFullName, su.username AS suUserName, su.mem_id AS suMemId 
FROM notify_post np 
    LEFT JOIN userfeed pf ON np.response_id IS NULL AND pf.id=np.post_id
    LEFT JOIN userresponses pr ON np.response_id IS NOT NULL AND pr.userfeed_id=np.post_id

    JOIN users su ON 
        (np.response_id IS NULL AND su.id=pf.user_id) 
        OR 
        (np.response_id IS NOT NULL AND su.id=pr.user_id AND pr.id=np.response_id)

WHERE np.user_id=1 
    AND pf.user_id NOT IN (SELECT bk.block_id FROM block bk WHERE bk.user_id=1 AND bk.block_id=pf.user_id)
    AND np.user_id!=su.id
ORDER BY np.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score -1):

Rethink the schema design.  This pattern is really bad for performance:

```
WHERE (x IS NULL     AND ...)
   OR (x IS NOT NULL AND ...)
```

It shows up clearly in that form in one case (`ON`), plus two less-obvious places.